# Different TextBox formatting in edit mode

Tags: wpf, textbox

In our WPF project, we are using a TextBox to let the user enter some length measures. This measures may be in millimeters, centimeters, inches, etc (depending on the user configuration).

We need to show the numbers on the TextBox along with the current measurement unit, like:
"120 mm"
"16 cm"
"1' 2 3/4"
and so on.

I am using ValueConverter to both perform the unit converting and to add the extra formatting. The UpdateSourceTrigger is default, so the binding applies when the user leaves the control.

The challenge here is that while editing the value, these "mm" or "cm" are not shown. So the previous examples in edit mode would be:
"120"
"16"
"1 2 3/4"

How can I make that happen?

Here is the Converter code for some cenários:

```
/// <summary>
/// Converts and formats the value (in milimeters) to the required unit/format
/// </summary>
public class LengthConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        LengthUnit unit = MainWindow.CurrentLengthUnit;

        switch (unit.Id)
        {
            case 1: //Milimeters
                return value + " mm";
            case 2: //Centimeters
                return (double)value / 10.0 + " cm";
            default:
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Unknown length unit.");

        }

    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType,
           object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        string rawValue = value as string;

        LengthUnit unit = MainWindow.CurrentLengthUnit;

        switch (unit.Id)
        {
            case 1: //Milimeters
                return rawValue.Replace("mm", "").Trim();
            case 2: //Centimeters
                return Double.Parse(rawValue.Replace("cm", "").Trim()) * 10.0;
            default:
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Unknown length unit.");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Append the unit after the value. Or can try something like split and join with the unit.

Comment: Post ValueConverter code.

Comment: Note sure if the Converter is a way to go, since it will be called only after the user leaves the control.
Using a getfocus() handler may be an option, but I think this would activate the binding mechanism...

Comment: Could be wrong, but this looks like a non-starter. Unless you put something in there to detect existing 'mm'/'cm'/etc. strings then you're going to either keep appending more and more of them, or throw an exception when (double)value fails on '10 cm'.

Comment: The converter logic will be surely improved, if this is the way to go. The point here to know if the strategy is good. Appending or removing the units is not enough, since value converting is necessary.
At this moment, my concern is how to show a different converting logic when the control is under edit by the user. Any ideas?

Answer (score 5):

What about this:
view:

```
<TextBox>
        <TextBox.Style>
            <Style TargetType="TextBox">
                <Style.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="False">
                            <Setter Property="Text">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource LengthConverter}">
                                        <Binding Path="Foo"/>
                                        <Binding Path="Text" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Mode=Self}"/>
                                    </MultiBinding>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Text" Value="{Binding Foo}"></Setter>
                        </Trigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </TextBox.Style>
    </TextBox>
```

converter:

```
public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
    if (values.Count() > 1)
    {
      var value = values[1].ToString();
      if (value != String.Empty)
      {
        int output;
        Int32.TryParse(value, out output);
        if (output != (int)values[0])
          return value;
      }
    }
    return String.Format("{0} {1}", values[0], "mm");      
}
```

Comment: Thank you Anka. Your approach seems promising. I am testing it right now and it seems there is a problem when there is a validation error. I am binding to a numeric value at binding source (double) and if I type "abc" on the text box I get the error properly. But if the control lost focus, the text will change to the previous valid binding, the red box around the control will be still there. Then, in I focus the control again, the erroneous value will be there...
I was thinking there could be a way to use triggers to change only the converter instead of the binding object. Any ideas?

Comment: Thank you again Anka. I manage to find a way to go (read my reply). But if I come up with a problem in my approach I will go back to yours straight away.

Answer (score 0):

So far I managed to fix this problem using only MultiBinding and passing the TextBox control as a parameter (not very nice I suppose).

On the converter code, I check for the control property "IsFocused" and return values the way I need. I am not able to pass the "IsFocused" property directly on the binding because it is readonly while the TextBox is two way bound to the source.

The following code shows some additional handlers used to "force" binding when the controls gain or loose focus.

```
<TextBox x:Name="leadInTextBox"
                     LostFocus="SizeLostFocus"
                     MouseDoubleClick="SelectText"
                     GotKeyboardFocus="SelectText"
                     PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown="SelectivelyMouseButton"
                     PreviewTextInput="PreviewTextInput">
                    <TextBox.Text>
                        <MultiBinding Mode="TwoWay" Converter="{StaticResource MultiLengthConverter}" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged" NotifyOnValidationError="True">
                            <Binding Source="{x:Static local:ApplicationService.UserInfo}" Path="LeadIn" StringFormat="F2" Mode="TwoWay" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged"/>
                            <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}" Path="." />
                        </MultiBinding>
                    </TextBox.Text>
                </TextBox>
```

converter:

```
public class MultiLengthConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{

    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        LengthUnit currentUnit = ApplicationService.UserInfo.LengthUnit;
        TextBox txtBox = values[1] as TextBox;

        switch (currentUnit)
        {
            case LengthUnit.Millimeter:
                return String.Format("{0:N2}{1}", values[0], txtBox.IsFocused == true ? string.Empty : " mm");
            case LengthUnit.Centimeter:
                return String.Format("{0:N2}{1}", (double)values[0] / 10.0, txtBox.IsFocused == true ? string.Empty : " cm");
            case LengthUnit.DecimalInch:
                return String.Format("{0:N2}{1}", (double)values[0] / 25.4, txtBox.IsFocused == true ? string.Empty : " in");
            default:
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Unknown length unit.");

        }
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        string rawValue = value as string;

        LengthUnit currentUnit = ApplicationService.UserInfo.LengthUnit;

        object ret;

        switch (currentUnit)
        {
            case LengthUnit.Millimeter:
                ret = Double.Parse(rawValue.Replace("mm", "").Trim());
                break;
            case LengthUnit.Centimeter:
                ret = Double.Parse(rawValue.Replace("cm", "").Trim()) * 10.0;
                break;
            case LengthUnit.DecimalInch:
                ret = Double.Parse(rawValue.Replace("in", "").Trim()) * 25.4;
                break;
            default:
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Unknown length unit.");
        }

        return new object[] { ret, null };
    }
}
```